# How to name a directory by combining two variables?

Tags: shell-script

I want to name a directory by combining the the values of two variables.
eg:  `dirname="$var1" '.' "$var2"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dirname="${var1}${var2}"
mkdir -p -- "$dirname"
```

Comment: $var1.=$var2                                                  mkdir var1                                                    It also works

Comment: @user95222 Not in `bash` (4.2.53). You probably mean `var1+=$var2`